# Good (CI) Continuous Integration Software for our situation

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, continuous-integration, hudson

Currently we are using Hudson (Jenkins) at my company.  Which is working for us, and it is completely free.  We use it mainly for C# .Net windows applications, however.

We love it for the most part, but parts of it feel janky:

- Crashes on us occasionally
- Built for Java, not C#
- MSTest and MSBuild integration is not very good in my opinion, relies on plugins
- It's free, so I feel like going with a paid option *could* be better

We are looking for a more commercial solution, is there some CI software out there that satisfies the following needs:

1. Works with multiple source control options.  Mainly need SVN and Git, but Mercurial and TFS would be nice also.
2. Runs on Windows and can use MSBuild for C# projects
3. Can run command line during builds
4. Can run remote SSH commands and SFTP files to Linux servers, we can fall back on #3 to get this done with command-line tools, though
5. Can run MSTest and NUnit tests for C# projects
6. Has a remote API of some kind where we can trigger builds from other servers

Is there something out there that would work well for us?  Any other opinions?

Comment: [Visual Build](http://www.kinook.com/VisBuildPro/)

Comment: "It's free, so I feel like going with a paid option would be better" - Whaaaaat? How does that have any bearing on quality?

Comment: Which is better Visual Studio, MonoDevelop, or SharpDevelop?  Paid options are just generally better quality than open source.  I am not saying anything against open source, as it's great.  You can just generally develop better software when you are paid for it.

Comment: @Jonathan.Peppers That's a function of the size of development team, age of the product, situation of the company, community, cause and effort driving the product. It's price has nothing to do with the quality. (also: Visual Studio Express is free - is it still the same quality as SharpDevelop? If you had to pay for SharpDevelop would it suddenly become better?)

Comment: Which is better: Firefox, Google Chrome or Netscape Navigator 3?

Comment: @Jonathan.Peppers Best Java IDE ? Its an opinion, but I would think the top ones are Eclipse and NetBeans. Both of which are free. I can provide many more examples if you want...

Comment: @viraptor, @Tnem, this conversation is not related to the question.

Comment: @Jonathan.Peppers But.... someone is WRONG on the internet! ;) (xkcd.com/386/)

Comment: @viraptor, pretty funny, that's why I wanted to call a truce before someone got a black eye.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) is a great paid for CI Server that I think will satisfy your needs.

Since CC.NET is not really maintained anymore, it isn't a very good option.

EDIT: CC.NET is being maintained

Comment: Where did you get the idea that CC.Net is no longer maintained?  Their checkin page (https://groups.google.com/group/ccnet-checkins?hl=en) seems to have a lot of activity for a dead project.

Comment: I stand corrected.  I had heard that from the build masters at work, and assumed it to be true.

Comment: TeamCity looks awesome so far, I think we're going with it.  Only thing lacking is the SSH linux stuff, but we can run putty command line to get it done.

Answer (score 4):

There are plenty out there.

If you are using Visual Studio 2010 with TFS 2010; then there is team build there.

But for you I'd highly recommend CruiseControl.NET, quick and easy to set up, and very powerful; you can tie it into the SCM you've noted, and fire off custom actions for the unit tests etc.

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same question a while back: [Bamboo Vs. Hudson(a.k.a. Jenkins) vs Any other CI systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806331/bamboo-vs-hudsona-k-a-jenkins-vs-any-other-ci-systems)

I've decided to give Altassian's product a try.

Answer (score 0):

We use [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) in conjunction to [NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/index.html) that could satisfy all your need but CruiseControl is still built in java.. You could use CruiseControl.NET instead.